# CardView leaves a gap on top

Tags: android, user-interface, android-relativelayout, android-cardview

On the left is how I would like my app to look, and how it is on the android studio preview. the image is aligned to CardView top.

on the right is how it actually looks. with a gap.

I tried both with linear layout, and with relative layout. doesn't work.[image]
here is my code:

EDIT:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:id="@+id/testCardView"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/medium_margin"
android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/medium_margin"
android:animateLayoutChanges="true"
app:cardCornerRadius="3dp"
app:cardUseCompatPadding="true">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/fullCardLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/reward_card_height"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:paddingLeft="@dimen/medium_margin"
        >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imgProvider"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/tiny_margin"
            android:src="@mipmap/rewards_amazon_icon"/>
```

.........

Comment: did you try to set margin top and left  to your ImageView ?

Comment: Can you post all the xml  ?

Comment: Yes for some reason it didn't include the CardView,
Now I posted from the start until the image view part,

Answer (score 0):

Try some like this:

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_margin="20dp"
        android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried negative margin like `android:layout_marginRight="-10dp"`? Also you can try just put both `CardView` and ImageView into `RelativeLayout` as a workaround.

Comment: hey @Alexander, Both of them didn't work.
the first one just narrowed the gap outside of the card.
the second one didn't work

Answer (score 0):

using a minus margin didn't work:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:id="@+id/testCardView"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/medium_margin"
android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/medium_margin"
android:animateLayoutChanges="true"
app:cardCornerRadius="3dp"
app:cardUseCompatPadding="true">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/fullCardLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/reward_card_height"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_marginTop="-5dp"
        android:paddingLeft="@dimen/medium_margin"
        >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imgProvider"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/tiny_margin"
            android:src="@mipmap/rewards_amazon_icon"/>[![enter image description here][1]][1]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use this tags.

```
card_view:cardPreventCornerOverlap="false"
card_view:cardUseCompatPadding="true"
```